# Compute and rename columns at the same time in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rename, calculated-columns

I have a data.table with a column "year" containing birth years:

```
library(data.table)

people <- data.table("year" = 1990:1992)
```

I would like to rename this column to "age" and compute the values at the same time in data.table:

```
setnames(people, c("year"), c("age" := 2023 - "age"))

setnames(people, c("year"), c("age" := 2023 - "year"))
```

Why isn't my code working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About "*why not working?*", you should check with the usage of `setnames`. When you type `?setnames`, you see the syntax

```
setnames(x,old,new,skip_absent=FALSE)
```

and the argument `new` is described as below:

> Optional. It can be a function or the new column names. If a function,
> it will be called with old and expected to return the new column
> names. The new column names must be the same length as columns
> provided to old argument.

You can assign a new name, but not a named column

---

To make it work, you can use the chaining expression like below

```
> people[, age := 2023 - year][, year := NULL][]
   age
1:  33
2:  32
3:  31
```

Answer (score 2):

We can change the names using *setnames*, then calculate the age:

```
setnames(people, old = "year", new = "age")[, age := 2023 - age]

people
#    age
# 1:  33
# 2:  32
# 3:  31
```

**Note:** Tomas's answer explains the "why *setnames* didn't work". This answer is to follow OP's original intent of using *setnames*, showing it is possible to chain `[]` after *setnames*.

Comment: '*Why isn't my code working?*'

Comment: @Mark it is already explained in Tomas's answer.